# pdegrad, Matlab, more output data than input

Tags: matlab, pde

I have a problem with the command pdegrad.

```
[ux,uy] = pdegrad(points,tri,dat);
```

`dat` and the `mesh` parameters comme form an other code that I download on Matlab.

Assume that the variable `dat` has `N` elements, `points` has `N` number of elements and `tri` has "`t` number of elements. Then, after computaion of `pdegrad` the number of element of `ux` and `uy` will be `t`. That's my problem, why it doesn't conserve the same length than dat. Because after, I need the product between `ux` and `dat` .

Thank you a lot for your help.

B.Y

Ps: You should know that computation of `pdegrad` gives the expected result

Comment: The [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/pdegrad.html) states that you'd better switch to the recommended function [`evaluateGradient`](http://mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/evaluategradient.html). That being said, did you read through the docs? I think you can find the answer there.

Comment: I tried your proposition, but I got this message _Undefined function or variable_ `evaluateGradient`. that weird, because I have the 'pde' toolbox, so I should have this function too.